# How To Add A Blacklist to Location

Tags: javascript

I am working on something to blacklist unwanted locations with the location service. Here is my current code:

How can I implement a blacklist feature?

```js
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
 // Locate position
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayPosition, errorFunction);
} else {
 alert('Your device location is not approved.');
}

// Success callback function
function displayPosition(pos) {
 var mylat = pos.coords.latitude;
 var mylong = pos.coords.longitude;
 var thediv = document.getElementById('locationinfo');
  alert('Your HWID is compliant of ProtoProt regulations.');
}
  function errorFunction(pos) {
 alert('Error: (PROTOPROT_POS_DENIED). We only use your HWID for checking compliance. Enable location to enter.');
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a list of locations given by two points w,y.

Each w,y represent the two opposite points of a w,x,y,z square which represents the blacklisted location.

Each point has longitude and latitude coordinates, so w = [long, lat] and y = [long, lat]

With those, you can rebuild all the [long, lat] of all the w,x,y,z corners of your square, thus representing the blacklisted area.

Now, it's rather easy to know the boundaries of forbidden location: any point [long, lat] which is within the square is blacklisted.

You can store those values within a Javascript Object (a dictionary) which can be stored in a distinct ".js" file. JSON representation could look like:

```
blacklisted_areas = {
  'area 51' : [w, y], // Replace w y with the floats of long and lat
  'pink unicorn zoo' : [w, y], // same
  // etc.
};
```

Access:

```
long = blacklisted_area['area 51'][0]
```

Comment: so how would I store these values, if possible separately from the main script file

Comment: so I import the distant file and on my main script how would I compare the values to that of the user's, and then check if it is blacklisted (sorry not good with js)

Comment: you will have to ask that one in another question thread on stackoverflow :-)